# How to access variable name which include a hyphen in Ansible

Tags: ansible, yaml

I have a simple vlan config file which I like to have the keys to match with JunOS syntax (this way I can pass them as aggrogate if I need to), so I'm using the `vlan-id` key like this example variable file.

```yaml
# vlans.yaml
vlans:
    - name: general
      description: "General"
      vlan-id: 100
    - name: hotline
      description: "Accounting"
      vlan-id: 110
```

but i can't access the vlan-id key because of the hyphen

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.vlan-id }}"
      loop: "{{ vlans }}"
      tags: debug
```

```
"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'vlan'
```

if I output the item directly I can see the key

```
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ vlans }}
```

```
ok: [SW02] => (item={'name': 'external', 'description': 'External', 'vlan-id': 209}) => {
    "msg": {
        "description": "External",
        "name": "external",
        "vlan-id": 209
    }
}
ok: [SW01] => (item={'name': 'external', 'description': 'External', 'vlan-id': 209}) => {
    "msg": {
        "description": "External",
        "name": "external",
        "vlan-id": 209
    }
}
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 5):

Put the attributes into the brackets '[]' aka **array notation**. For example,

```yaml
        msg: "{{ item['vlan-id'] }}"
```

Quoting from: [Ansible allows dot notation and array notation for variables. Which notation should I use?](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html#ansible-allows-dot-notation-and-array-notation-for-variables-which-notation-should-i-use)

> If your variable contains dots (.), colons (:), or dashes (-), if a key begins and ends with two underscores, or if a key uses any of the known public attributes, it is safer to use the **array notation**.

---

Q: ***"This is not a variable, it's the key."***

A: Right. The only restriction is the keys are unique. Quoting from [YAML 1.2](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2764044)

> **Mapping**. The content of a mapping node is an unordered set of key: value node pairs, with the restriction that each of the **keys is unique**. **YAML places no further restrictions on the nodes**. In particular, keys may be arbitrary nodes, the same node may be used as the value of several key: value pairs, and a mapping could even contain itself as a key or a value (directly or indirectly).

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work. and I can even use sub item's with it.