# Ansible: 'assert' task looking for unexpected name

Tags: automation, ansible, jinja2

I try to verify that my docker compose suit is up with task

```yaml
- name: Verify that web and db services are running
  ansible.builtin.assert:
    that:
      - "output.services.artifactory-exporter-pdp.devopsmonitoring_artifactory-exporter-pdp_1.state.running"
  ...
```

this give me a failure message:

```json
2023-07-20T13:57:06.2633470Z fatal: [server]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'output.services.artifactory-exporter-pdp.devopsmonitoring_artifactory-exporter-pdp_1.state.running' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (output.services.artifactory-exporter-pdp.devopsmonitoring_artifactory-exporter-pdp_1.state.running): 'dict object' has no attribute 'artifactory'"}
```

and in the associated output I clearly see that it's a 1:1 match.

Are there any special characters here that I should escape, or something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Are there any special characters here that I should escape?*

Yes, according to [Creating valid variable names](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_variables.html#creating-valid-variable-names)

> *Not all strings are valid Ansible variable names. A variable name can only include letters, numbers, and underscores. Python keywords or playbook keywords are not valid variable names.*

That's why the string gets cut off and you get an error message

```
'dict object' has no attribute 'artifactory'
```

as the systems if looking for

```
output.services.artifactory
```

which is obviously not existing.

You may try with [array notation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63439416/6771046)

```yaml
output.services['artifactory-exporter-pdp']['devopsmonitoring_artifactory-exporter-pdp_1'].state.running
```

**Similar Q&A**

- [How to access variable name which include a hyphen in Ansible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63437205/)
- [Ansible templating skips string after a dash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52396704/6771046)

Comment: I just begin my ansible adventure so I must have overlooked this part... Thank you!